# GWT RPC basics control flow explanation

Tags: gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc

I am new to GWT and am able to work around with GWT RPC but have problem in understanding how the control flow takes place internally. How it gets translated to AJAX?

Can we use `new()` instead of `GWT.create(someService.class)` to make an RPC call?
Why does Google not just use Async version instead of creating 2 interfaces?

What happens internally when we use

```
TaskService Async = GWT.create(TaskService.class);
```

I have read that it chooses the browser specific `hashname.js` file but am not understanding the complete control flow. Also How is the Callback Object used.

Can someone explain the control flow by pointing out the essentials?

**UPDATE** : @Thomas Broyer, Everything I understood... Just confirming that in case GWT.create() there is a .rpc file in the client side which helps in the deferred(late/runtime) binding. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `GWT.create()` will in this case call a GWT generator; it'll generate a class implementing the Async interface (and that's why you only have to declare an interface and you never implement it yourself).
   See [RPC Plumbing Diagram](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuidePlumbingDiagram).
   Using a generator (or selecting a specific implementation, but in the case of GWT-RPC, a generator is used) is called [deferred binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html).
2. So, no, you cannot use `new`.
3. As to why there are 2 interfaces, this is so that GWT can check that your server-side code (synchronous) is consistent with your client-side code (async). The reason you call `GWT.create` on the *synchronous* interface and it returns an implementation of the async one is legacy. I bet they wouldn't do it that way, were they to re-implement GWT-RPC from scratch.
4. The generated class will be responsible of serializing the call (method name and arguments) and make an AJAX request (using a `RequestBuilder`); and then deserialize the response (either of the type declared, or an exception)
5. Because calls are asynchronous, the callback is used to, well, call your code back when the server responds, after deserialization takes place (so either calling `onSuccess` with the decoded object, or `onFailure` with the decoded exception).
   See [Getting Used to Asynchronous Calls](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideGettingUsedToAsyncCalls)

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Can You just confirm the update. Best Regards.

Comment: The "deferred" in _deferred binding_ means "at compile-time, rather than when writing the code", it's not "at runtime". The *.gwt.rpc file is used on the server-side only (AFAIK), as it communicates to the server code (which itself is independent from the GWT compilation) how the client has been compiled re. the classes going through GWT-RPC.

Comment: So any class which is there in the client side will be present in all the .cache.html files generated (so they all help in deferred binding). So why is it such that the internal class generated (implementing the Async interface) is linked to deferred binding so specifically?

Comment: In your code, you `GWT.create()` some interface, you don't code against its real implementation; but at compile-time, the `GWT.create()` is somehow _resolved_ (in this case, calls generator) and _bound_ to a concrete implementation: this is deferred binding; your code isn't _bound_ to a specific implementation, the choice of the implementation is _deferred_ until compile-time (by the GWT compiler, not the Java compiler). The `*.gwt.rpc` file will tell the server that the `xxx/12345` in the request is actually `java.util.ArrayList` (it's a bit more complicated, but basically it works that way)

Comment: Okk. So the term "deferred binding" is a big term given to an ordinary concept. The *.gwt.rpc thing now I am understanding why it is used now. Thanks alot for your patience. Now I will try to unearth some more concepts in GWT. :)